# Trouble with running behat through the composer

Tags: php, behat, mink, gentoo

I have a very odd trouble with running behat through the composer (php bin/behat). When i'm trying to do it i got nothing. Even no single error... 
When i'm trying do it through phar (php behat.phar -h) everithing ik Ok. I can't understand this magic.

What am i doing wrong?

I can use behat through phar, but the link in official documentation is not working  ($ wget https://github.com/downloads/Behat/Mink/mink.phar). I got 404

- **PHP 5.5.24-pl0-gentoo (cli) (built: Apr 28 2015 11:39:57)** 
      Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
     with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
     with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can install Behat with composer, but you can't run it with composer.
When you use system wide installation you should have behat script somewhere in /usr/local/bin.
Might help to reinstall Behat.